# How to fix if code is stopping after taking the input

Tags: python

I'm a learner so I was just making this basic calculator program. But whenever I run it, it stops after taking the "abcd" var input.

```
first_number = input("Enter first number: ")
second_number = input("Enter second number: ")

abcd = input("A for addition, S for subtraction, M for multiplication, D for division ")

if abcd.upper == "A":
    sum = float(first_number) + float(second_number)
    print("Sum: ",sum)

elif abcd.upper == "S":
    difference = float(first_number) - float(second_number)
    print("difference: ",difference)

elif abcd.upper == "M":
    product = float(first_number) * float(second_number)
    print("product: ",product)

elif abcd.upper == "D":
    quotient = float(first_number) // float(second_number)
    print("quotient: ",quotient)
```

Comment: you mean upper function? It should be `abcd.upper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets to run methods.

```
...
if abcd.upper() == "A":
    sum = float(first_number) + float(second_number)
    print("Sum:", sum)
...
```

Don't use 'sum' as variable, because it's a function name. You can use `sum(float(first_number), float(second_number))` to get sum of 2 or more variables.

If you want to keep it on after each result, read about `while loop` here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Basic issue is that you are using `upper`. It is a function, so change `abcd.upper` with `abcd.upper()` in `if` conditions.

```
first_number = input("Enter first number: ")
second_number = input("Enter second number: ")

abcd = input("A for addition, S for subtraction, M for multiplication, D for division ")
if abcd.upper() == "A":
    sum = float(first_number) + float(second_number)
    print("Sum: ",sum)

elif abcd.upper() == "S":
    difference = float(first_number) - float(second_number)
    print("difference: ",difference)

elif abcd.upper() == "M":
    product = float(first_number) * float(second_number)
    print("product: ",product)

elif abcd.upper() == "D":
    quotient = float(first_number) // float(second_number)
    print("quotient: ",quotient)
```